# check if the email is already in database when creating a new acount

Tags: php, mysql

So i want to check if the email is already in database when creating a new account but i do not know how to make it work , because i am a beginner in php

```
 <?php         

    if (isset($_POST["register"])) 
{

 include 'header.php';

$firstName = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);          
$email = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);  
$password = sha1($connection->real_escape_string($_POST["password"])); 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%$email%'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if($queryResult >0)
      echo"Email already exists";

else 
{
            $connection = new mysqli('mysql.hostinger.com', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');



        $data = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$firstName', '$email', '$password')");

        if ($data === false)
            echo "Eroare!";
        else
         header( 'Location:http://alergii-help.tk/account/login.php');
    }}                 
?> 



  <input type="submit"   class="login100-form-btn"   name="register" value="Inregistrare" required />
```

i don't know what is not working

the table is caled "article"

Comment: You shouldn't use `like` when you want an exact comparison, otherwise you'll get incorrect answers. Such as `me@me.com` will match with `1me@me.com` and so on, yet are two different email addresses

Comment: Use prepared statements. Your code is deeply troubling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add a unique constraint for email in the table using below query?

```
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_EML UNIQUE (EMAIL)
```

If your code tries to insert an already existing email, then MySQL will throw such duplicate data exception while inserting and you can easily catch it and identify. Below is pseudo code to check.

```
if( mysql_errno() == 1062) {
    // Duplicate key
} else {
    // Non duplicate
}
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html

Comment: and how do i add it ?

Comment: @PainKiller Added the constraint query for your table

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php         
if (isset($_POST["register"])) {

    include 'header.php';
    $connection = new mysqli('xxxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxxx');
    $firstName = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);          
    $email = strtolower($connection->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]));  
    $password = sha1($connection->real_escape_string($_POST["password"])); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(email) = '$email';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($queryResult >0)
        echo"Email already exists";
    } else {
            $data = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$firstName', '$email', '$password')");
            if ($data === false) {
                echo "Eroare!";
            } else {
                header( 'Location:http://alergii-help.tk/account/login.php');
            }
    }
}                 
?>
```

Comment: i do not have the create account button anymore

Comment: i have it under the " ?> "

Answer (score 0):

You need the first make the connection and then pass it before statement:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
```

like below:

```
$conn = new mysqli('mysql.hostinger.com', 'u784726611_teze', 'b567c63b567c63', 'u784726611_teze');

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: i have the connection in header.php

Comment: if $con is already alive then use the following:
$data = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$firstName', '$email', '$password')");